# How to capture FCM notification in an activity while the activity is in foreground?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have FCM push notification setup in my android project.

I have a class

```
public class MyFcmListenerService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message) {
        // handle general push notifications
    }
}
```

In my AndoridManifest.xml, i have this

```
<service
    android:name=".model.integration.fcm.MyFcmListenerService"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Now in one of my Activity, I would like to make it so that when my app is in the foreground, this Activity handles the Fcm notificaiton directly, without the FirebaseMessagingService stuff doing anything.

How do I do that?

When it was gcm, i used a BroadcastReceiver and the register the broadcastReceiver in that particular activity. That BroadcastReceiver used an `IntentFilter` and I can just call `abortBroadcast()` to stop the `FirebaseMessagingService` from doing its default stuff.

But what do I do in the FCM case? How do I capture the push notification in the broadcastReceiver in my Activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating some static method in the FCMService to set some variables in my onResume and onPause of my Activity.

This way, so that when I receive messages from FcmService, i can conditionally skip some notifications.

Comment: What methods did you call? This sounds interesting.

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier Sorry buddy i wasn't clear enough. I created those static methods and static fields. So i can manually decide what kind of push notifications can be skipped.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 parts of notification. One is "notification" block and another is "data" block. If you send the data in "notification" block then you can get the access to the data only when the app is in foreground, but if you send the data in "data" block then you can get the access to the data anytime even if the app is closed. To get the data when data is sent in "notification" block, just simply do:

```
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message) {
    // If the data is sent in "notification" block then
    message.getNotification().getTitle() //for Title
    message.getNotification().getBody() //for body
    message.getNotification().getClickAction() //for clickAction
    //etc...

    //Build your notification here using notification builder and the data you have
}
```

To get the data when data is sent in "data" block, just simply do:

```
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message) {
    // If the data is sent in "data" block then
    Map<String, String> data = message.getData();

    //Now extract any data you want as it is a Map using keys that you would have sent in the "data" block

    //Build your notification here using notification builder and the data you have

}
```